# Typing accented characters in JavaFX 2 applications not working?

Tags: javafx-2

I'm developing a javafx-2 application and I want the user to be able to type Greek accented characters in a Textfield  using a 'dead key'. Unfortunately, the accents are ignored. The javafx-2 samples provided by oracle behave the same way.

I've only checked on a mac running Lion. Java Swing applications don't have this problem. I have installed the latest JRE provided by apple (1.6.0_31-b04-414).

Thanks,
Nikos

Comment: i've tested entering from keyboard, it works in fx 2.1, see updated answer below.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I suppose this means there's probably something wrong with my system. On the other hand, I only have this problem with javafx applications (on my macbook running lion). Does anyone have any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: yes, both fx 2.1 and 2.2

Comment: my test was on Win7, I'll try Mac tomorrow. Maybe that's a reason

Comment: And I'll try Win7 tomorrow :). Thanks

Comment: @NikosP. hey! I have the same problem but I'm currently using Linux. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I haven't used javafx for a while but I think this issue (https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-20882) is fixed for mac. Not sure for linux though.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try JavaFX 2.1 (dev preview: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html)

I had no problems with Greek accented characters there:

[image]

**UPD**: Typing these characters works as well in 2.1, see screenshot with characters entered from keyboard using dead keys for Greek Polytonic keyboard:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I can paste from clipboard such characters but I can't type them (I'm already using JavaFX 2.1 developer preview)

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem with FX8. One solution would be to write a textproperty listener to take care of that, unless it is fixed later on. Coming from Swing it is true I did not have that problem either. I am using Windows7.